# Can the exponential map (in Lie theory) be considered an example of a functor?

Tags: category-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, functors

I've heard that the exponential map from the Lie algebra of a Lie group to the original Lie group can be considered as a functor of some sort, but I'm very new to all this and would appreciate some clarification. If this is true, a brief explanation of what exactly this functor is would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think one of the key issues in defining this functor would have to be in the surjectivity of the exponential map for various Lie groups/algebras.  I can imagine there being problems if it’s not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The exponential map is not a functor, but a natural transformation. This is a formalization that, if $\varphi:G\to H$ is a map of Lie groups and $D\varphi:{\mathfrak g}\to {\mathfrak h}$ is its derivative viewed as a map of Lie algebras, then we have an equality ${\rm exp}_H\circ D\varphi=\varphi\circ {\rm exp}_G$ of maps $\mathfrak g\to H$. The functors at issue here are the forgetful functor from Lie groups to smooth manifolds and the functor from Lie groups to smooth manifolds sending $G\mapsto \mathfrak g$ and $\varphi\mapsto D\varphi$.

Comment: This answer, as it stands, seems wrong to me. How can you have a functor from Lie groups to smooth manifolds sending $G\mapsto \mathfrak g$ and $\varphi\mapsto D\varphi$? $\mathfrak g$ is a Lie algebra, not a smooth manifold. The point is that exp is a mapping from objects in different categories (lie algebras to manifolds). So it looks more like a functor than a natural transformation (which are morphisms inside a single category).  Can you please explain?

Comment: @magma You’ve misread the answer. It is a natural transformation between (1) the forgetful functor from Lie groups to smooth manifolds and (2) the functor sending a Lie group to its Lie algebra. Both have codomain smooth manifolds.

Answer (score 2):

There are non-isomorphic Lie groups that have isomorphic Lie algebras -- for example take $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $PSL_2(\mathbb{R}) = SL_2(\mathbb{R})/\{\pm1\}$.  So certainly you cannot expect a functor that always returns the group you started with.

You can however rectify this by say requiring the Lie group to be simply connected.